# Merge NodeJS project with .NET project in VisualStudio

Tags: node.js, .net, visual-studio

I have a .NET WebAPI web application which I develop in VisualStudio.

I also have a NodeJS project for running UI tests (on this website) with Cypress, which I develop in Webstorm/VSCode.

I want to merge them to one project, so it will be more comfortable handling code and versions (git, deployments) in one place (VisualStudio, I guess).

How can I do that? How can I merge them + how can I ran them after that?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some digging I found it.

1. I needed to update my VisualStudio to support nodeJS projects (with visual studio installer).
2. In my solution I created a new blank NodeJS Web Application project (right click on the solution > add new project > choose the right type).
3. I copied there all my files from the second project - without the node modules directory.
4. On the new project > npm > right click > [install the npm packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/npm-package-management?view=vs-2019).
   (Also you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/develop-javascript-code-without-solutions-projects?view=vs-2019))
5. My package json had this code:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "cy:open": "cypress open",
       "cy:run": "cypress run"
     },
   ```

...so I run CMD in my project folder `> npm run cy:open`
(There might be some easier ways, but some of them made my Chrome crush so I used this way)